# Jasmine SpyObj doesn't return mocked object

Tags: javascript, angular, jasmine2.0

I'm trying to test the following service.

```
@Injectable()
export class TranslationService {

  language = 'NL';

  constructor(contextService: ContextService) {
    let context = contextService.getContext();
    this.language = context.language;
  }
}
```

The actual test:

```html
describe('TranslationService', () => {

  let service: TranslationService;
  let contextServiceSpy: jasmine.SpyObj<ContextService>;

  beforeEach(() => {

    const contextSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('ContextService', ['getContext']);
 
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        TranslationService,
        {provide: ContextService, useValue: contextSpy}]
    });

    service = TestBed.get(TranslationService);
    contextServiceSpy = TestBed.get(ContextService);
  
  });

  it('should create an instance', () => {

    const context: Context = {
      language: 'EN'
    };

    contextServiceSpy.getContext.and.returnValue(context);

    expect(service).toBeDefined();
    expect(contextServiceSpy.getContext.calls.count()).toBe(1, 'spy method was called once');
    expect(contextServiceSpy.getContext.calls.mostRecent().returnValue).toBe(context);
  });

});
```

Now when running my test it returns with an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'language' of undefined
```

This means that spy did not return my mocked context. But I don't have a clue why it isn't. Anyone?

I used https://angular.io/guide/testing#service-tests

angular 5.2.4

jasmine 2.8.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Service constructor is called before mocking `getContext` stub.

It should be:

```
contextServiceSpy = TestBed.get(ContextService);
contextServiceSpy.getContext.and.returnValue(context);
service = TestBed.get(TranslationService);
```

Comment: Pff.... thanks a lot! Now it is working as expected. From the documentation (https://angular.io/guide/testing#service-tests) it is not clear and it seems they are calling '....and.returnValue(..)' also after:   masterService = TestBed.get(MasterService);
  valueServiceSpy = TestBed.get(ValueService);

Comment: You are welcome. This can be done in the docs this way because mocked method isn't called on service class construction.

Comment: ah ok! Clear! Thanks a lot.